# Estimating gas of an ERC20 transfer

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I'd like to estimate the gas of a simple ERC20 transfer between two addresses. The web3.js docs on `estimateGas` are admittedly confusing:

```
// using the callback
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).estimateGas({gas: 5000000}, function(error, gasAmount){
    if(gasAmount == 5000000)
        console.log('Method ran out of gas');
});
```

The `myMethod(123)` is what I find confusing. What is that for? The following is what I'm currently thinking, but I'm getting `TypeError: contract.methods.send is not a function`. What should I substitute for `myMethod(123)`?

```
  try {
    await contract.methods
      .send("0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe")
      .estimateGas({ gas: 60000 }, (error, gasAmount) => {
        return gasAmount;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`send()` refers to a contract method called `send`. You do not have `send` in your Solidity Contract source code.

Instead, try `contract.methods.myMethod.send`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you need to look for the function in the smartcontract you want to call and replace `myMethod(123)` for the function in the contract you are calling.

For example, if you are working with the pancakeswap [contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0x73feaa1eE314F8c655E354234017bE2193C9E24E#code) and check in the code the function `function deposit(uint256 _pid, uint256 _amount) public {...}` (line 1674), you will need to do this:

```
const estimatedGas = await contract.methods.deposit(123, 0).estimateGas({from: "0x345})
```

You need to pass the args to deposit in order to make it work.